Is it possible to make Dan Fessler's method of pixel art in the compositor?
Is it possible to make Dan Fessler video but uses Photoshop

It just got me thinking if it's remotely possible. It's got

Color/Gradient Ramp
Posterize
Black and White (RGB to BW)

But when I apply a dither pattern like this 16x16 pixels image →←, it only crops the output image down to the size of the dither pattern (16x16). How can the actual size of the rendered image be maintained?


Hi, welcome to BSE! While external resources are fine as complement to your question, they should not be a requirement for understanding. Your question seems pretty hard to follow without having to get out of BSE and watch a video, please [edit] your question to add more information about what you expect to have, and what you currently get instead, what you tried. Don't hesitate to use screenshots too. Editing will queue up your question for reopening.

There is a free pixel art add-on for Blender that could be helpful.
